# コードにエラーがある時のメッセージボックスを非表示にしたい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio Community 2013です。
C# でコードにエラーがある時にソースを保存すると、このようなメッセージが毎回表示されます。

[image: 警告メッセージ]

私はソースを編集中にこまめに保存する癖があるので何度もメッセージが出て使いにくいです。
このメッセージを非表示に設定する方法をご存じの方は教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
拡張機能の [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) のオプション設定で
`PowerCommands` > `Remove and Sort Usings on save` を off にすると表示されなくなりました。

[image: Productivity Power Toolsのオプション]

Answer (score 1):

それは厳密にはVisual Studioの機能ではないように見えます。保存時のエラーではなく右クリック「usingの整理」のいずれかを実行した際のエラーメッセージです。保存時にこの機能が実行されるのは、別のツールに依るものではないでしょうか？

質問の、エラーを放置する方法については看過できません。というのもメッセージにある通り、たとえソースコードが完成してもビルドに成功することはありません。

[image: ソリューションエクスプローラー]

画像のようにソリューションエクスプローラーウィンドウにはプロジェクトの参照設定に何かしらエラーが発生しているはずであり、それを解消しましょう。（わからなければ削除してください。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りVisual Studioの機能ではない（Express Editionを使っている時には表示されなかった）かもしれません。拡張機能などを確認してみます。